# Scatter plot output is not showing

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash and trying to run the below code for a Scatter plot.The graph is coming but no data points in it.May I know where I went wrong

My Code

```
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash()

np.random.seed(42)

random_x = np.random.randint(1, 101, 100)
random_y = np.random.randint(1, 101, 100)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(
            id="Scatter Plot",
            figure={
                "Data": [
                    go.Scatter(
                        x=random_x,
                        y=random_y,
                        mode="markers",
                    )
                ],
                "layout": go.Layout(title="My Scatter Plot"),
            },
        )
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

My Output

[image]

Comment: maybe delete the empty line before mode='markers', ? or was that a copy & paste error?

Comment: Removed the empty line . Still not working

Comment: This is from memory, but I think it needs to be data instead of Data. Will check when I’m at my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct dictionary key for a figure is `"data"` rather than `"Data"`:

```py
fig = {
    "data": [
        go.Scatter(
            x=random_x,
            y=random_y,
            mode="markers",
        )
    ],
    "layout": go.Layout(title="My Scatter Plot"),
}
```